# Angular.js SVG bindings throw 404 before compilation

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I'm using jquery.svg.js to render some svg nodes, with angular expression bindings, and it works great: http://plnkr.co/edit/fOdpjL?p=preview

The issue is I'm getting 404 error from elements that have not yet been compiled by angular:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://run.plnkr.co/MD1XXVLd74eJnxWO/%7B%7B%22#" + model.id}
```

This is coming from line 81 on the plunkr:

```
var shapeForeground = ngSvg.svg.use(parentGroup, '{{"#" + model.id}}'
```

The 404s don't hurt anything, and the app works, but my console is full of errors, that I would prefer to not have, as it gets pretty noisy. I tried using `ng-attr-href` (aka late binding), but for some reason it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, [`ngHref`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref) was made for this! I'm not sure if/how it works with jQuery SVG though...

Comment: @stevuu that was it, thanks! If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented: [`ngHref`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref) was made for this!